# insert data from one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a problem locating comments for a given user with the following table structure:

```
usertable (id, userid, name)
comments (id, commentname, date)
```

*Note: `usertable.id` is not the same as `comments.id`, and they are both `autoincrement`*

How should I go about updating these tables to fix this problem?

---

**Update**

Is this code good for all users get their own votes when someone voted as thilo savage told me ?

```
$sth = thumbsup::db()->prepare(
     'INSERT INTO'
    .thumbsup::config('database_table_prefix')
    .'votes_users(vid, userid) VALUES (?,?)');

$sth->execute(array($this->vid, $userid));
```

Comment: You absolutely need to improve your question format.

Comment: When you say `id of usertable is not the same as id comments` then How were the ids in category table created, are they an autoincrement?

Comment: ids in category table created ? i dont understand what you mean. yes they are both autoincrements .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Rewritten to use many-to-many relationship because current tables can't be altered.

Create a new table called comments_users with these fields:
cuid (primary key and auto increment) | cid | uid

Then get all of a user's comments with this code:

```
    $user_id = '1234';

// get all the user's comment ids from comments_users table
$find = mysql_query("SELECT `cid` FROM `comments_users` WHERE `uid` = '".$user_id."'");

// generate a query that grabs all those comments
$load = "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE ";
while ($row  = mysql_fetch_array($find) {
    $load .= "`id` = '".$row['cid']."' OR ";
}

// shop off the last OR
$load = substr($load,0,-4);

// put all the user's comments into comments array
$q = mysql_query($load);
while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $comments[] = $comment
}

print_r($comments);
```

As far as inserting goes, you'll insert comments into the comments table like you normally would, but then you'd ALSO insert a row into comments_users table filling in the appropriate cid and uid for that comment

Comment: you mean the id of usertable and id of comments ?  i cant change them . i only want have sql code to write like sbrattla said. thanks for quick answer

Comment: i mean i  cant change them because they are already writen in all my php files . so i will look for them all !! lol . cant i write sql code to manage those ids and get comments for each user ? thanks

Comment: hej . thanks for this code thilo , i have created database table ( comments_users) but i dont understand why you make  $user_id = '1234'; and what i will do in this place 1234 . i have many users , i will choose one ?

Comment: i see you talking in chat rooms but i cant write there , koz of this reputation .

Comment: Hey! Just replace 1234 with whatever user's id you want comments from.  So say your URL is site.com/user?user=63 then you'd make $user_id = $_GET['user']; make sense?

Comment: hi ! no i didnt work this code which you gave me : $sth = votings_votes_users::db()->prepare('INSERT INTO
'.votings_votes_users::config('database_table_prefix').votings_votes_users
(vid, userid) VALUES (?,?)');
           $sth->execute(array($this->id, $user_id));  you gave me only insert but not to update or get data. this code didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options:

1. Add a 'uid' column to the comments table which references the usertable's 'id' column. That way, you have a way to keep track of which comments belong to which users.
2. Create a table 'user_comment' with the columns 'uid' and 'cid'. This option leaves the two existing tables as they are, and the 'user_comment' table is responsible for keeping track of which comments belong to which users.

Comment: thanks for quick help lol i like this site lol . but please can you give me the code of mysql to write in my php please. thanks

Comment: If you've created the two other tables, then creating the third one should not be harder than what you've already done. I'm fan of the belief that when one has to do some of the work, the learning outcome is greater than if everything was served on a silver plate. So, my advise is to get your hands dirty and try to get it up and running. If your having trouble with that, then you can always come back with a specific problem.

Comment: thanks for your advice  , im really enjoyed with  thilo savage he writed me the code . and the tables its not me who writed them , if it was me i was able to create the third. anyway if you can help welcome if not , you loose your time to write in my question .i writeed my question because really i cant create it . i have but it was errors .